# Row number column in OpenOffice calc

Tags: row, openoffice-calc, ods, openoffice-basic

I have a ods file containing two columns and 3700 rows.
I need to add a column to this file where the column will automatically show the row number, In the way that I get the pdf output, the content of each row is as follows:

1 | first row first column | The first row content of the second column
...
i (number) | ith row first column | The (ith) row content of the second column

Answer (score 0):

Enter `=ROW()` and then fill down.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ROW